# Spark structured streaming Elasticsearch integration issue. Data source es does not support streamed writing

Tags: apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I am writing a Spark structured streaming application in which data processed with Spark needs be sink'ed to elastic search.

This is my development environment, hence I have a standalone Elastic search.

I have tried following two ways to sink the data in the DataSet to ES.

1.`ds.writeStream().format("org.elasticsearch.spark.sql").start("spark/orders");`
2.`ds.writeStream().format("es").start("spark/orders");`

In both cases I am getting the following error:

Caused by:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Data source es does not support streamed writing
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.createSink(DataSource.scala:287) ~[spark-sql_2.11-2.1.1.jar:2.1.1]
at org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.DataStreamWriter.start(DataStreamWriter.scala:272) ~[spark-sql_2.11-2.1.1.jar:2.1.1]
at org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.DataStreamWriter.start(DataStreamWriter.scala:213) ~[spark-sql_2.11-2.1.1.jar:2.1.1]
```

### pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>

    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>

    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongo-spark-connector_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-hive_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
        <artifactId>elasticsearch-spark-20_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>5.6.1</version>
    </dependency>


Appreciate any help in resolving this issue.
```

Comment: I am running Spark 2.1.1 and ES 5.6.1

Comment: Did you guys succeed ? I got same issue right now

Answer (score 1):

you can try

```
 ds.write.format("org.elasticsearch.spark.sql").option("es.resource",ES_INDEX+"/"+ES_TYPE).option("es.mapping.id",ES_ID).mode("overwrite").save()
```

Comment: It is a streaming application. I wont be able to use write, I have to use writeStream isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

Elasticsearch sink does not support streamed writing which means you can't stream output to Elasticsearch.
You could write streaming output to kafka and using logstash to read from kafka to elasticsearch.

Answer (score 1):

**Update**:

Streamed Writing is now supported in version [Elasticsearch 6.x](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/current/spark.html#spark-sql-streaming-write) when using Spark 2.2.0.

Dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
    <artifactId>elasticsearch-spark-20_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>6.2.4</version>
</dependency>
```

writeStream code:

```
 ds
  .writeStream
  .outputMode(OutputMode.Append()) // only append mode is currently supported
  .format("es")
  .option("checkpointLocation", "/my/checkpointLocation")
  .option("es.mapping.id", "MY_OPTIONAL_ID_ATTRIBUTE")
  .trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
  .start("index/type")
```

Comment: Did this answer solve the problem? I have tried to implement a similar solution, the only difference was I had to use `.format("org.elasticsearch.spark.sql")`. I am seeing the following error  `org.elasticsearch.hadoop.EsHadoopIllegalArgumentException: Cannot determine write shards for [structuredTest/testType]; likely its format is incorrect (maybe it contains illegal characters? or all shards failed?) `

Comment: can you share your code?  could be an issue with your mappings

Comment: I have resolved the issue, it was due to the capitalised characters in the index. I wasn't aware they were not allowed.